# CSS Animation scrolling text not worknig in Edge browser(translate3d)

Tags: html, css

I have tried scrolling text, it's working fine in chrome. 
But it's not working in EDGE browser.
Below is my code. I have used animation name as ticker. And I applied animation.

```css
@keyframes ticker {
    0% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); }
  }
  .tcontainer{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .ticker-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
  }
  .ticker-move {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-right: 100%;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-name: ticker;
    animation-duration: 10s;
  }
  .ticker-move:hover{
    animation-play-state: paused;
  }
  .ticker-item{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 2rem;
  }
```

```html
<div class="tcontainer">
    <div class="ticker-wrap">
      <div class="ticker-move">
        <div class="ticker-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">Aliquam consequat varius consequat.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">Fusce dapibus turpis vel nisi malesuada sollicitudin.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">Pellentesque auctor molestie orci ut blandit.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It's not working on EDGE browser

Comment: I am using Edge version 44, it's not working

Comment: scrolling is not coming for edge, text is displaying as mention in html

Comment: Can you reproduce the bug with just the current question code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add cross browser css as below:

```css
   @keyframes ticker {
    0% { 
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    100% { 
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ticker {
    0% { 
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    100% { 
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes ticker {
    0% { 
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    100% { 
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes ticker {
    0% { 
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    100% { 
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes ticker {
    0% { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); }
}
  .tcontainer{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .ticker-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
  }
  .ticker-move {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-right: 100%;
    animation: ticker 10s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: ticker 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: ticker 10s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: ticker 10s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: ticker 10s linear infinite;
  }
  .ticker-move:hover{
    animation-play-state: paused;
  }
  .ticker-item{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 2rem;
  }
```

```html
<div class="tcontainer">
    <div class="ticker-wrap">
      <div class="ticker-move">
        <div class="ticker-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">Aliquam consequat varius consequat.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">Fusce dapibus turpis vel nisi malesuada sollicitudin.</div>
        <div class="ticker-item">Pellentesque auctor molestie orci ut blandit.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> You can also refer this link for more details:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: Actually translate3d(in EDGE) is not working. I don't know which one I need to add

Comment: I have updated the code..Please try this and let me know is it working or not?

Comment: No, code is working fine in chrome, in EDGE not working

Comment: Please check it again if you are making mistake anywhere, because the same code is working perfect in my Edge browser

Comment: Its working but text is not scrolling fully, all text is not scrolling fully, once half text scrolled then text comes from right to left scrolling. I need to scroll all text then it will come right to left scrolling